# One segment route for two different operations

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

i need to resolve a route of one segment to different behaviors with angular-ui router.

For example im doing this by:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('parent', {
        url: '/:route'
        template: '<div ui-view/>'
        controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', ($scope, $state, $stateParams)->

            # I get the type of route that the user is visiting checking server side and returning its type..
            switch typeOfRoute
                when "user"
                    $state.transitionTo('parent.user.profile')
                when "place"
                    $state.transitionTo('parent.place.page')
                else
                    alert("bad route")
        ]
        })
    .state('parent.user', {
        abstract: true
        template: '<div ui-view/>'
        })

    .state('parent.user.profile', {
        template: '<h1>This is a profile</h1>'
        controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', ($scope, $state, $stateParams)->

            # Here happens all about the user
        ]})

    .state('parent.place', {
        abstract: true
        template: '<div ui-view/>'
        })

    .state('parent.place.page', {
        template: '<h1>This is a place</h1>'
        controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', ($scope, $state, $stateParams)->

            # Here happens all about the place

        ]})
```

Using the example above if someone visits:

/Johndoe -> returns that route is a user and transitions to parent.user.profile
/Newyork -> returns that route is a place and transitions to parent.place.page

The problem using this method is that when i code the route to resolve /Johndoe/likes the browsers goes to /Johndoe again, im thinking of checking the length of params, etc... but maybe someone have done something similar and better.

Someone tried to built something similar? im stuck at this point.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i will post finally what i´ve done if can help to someone.

I replaced the above code with:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/:route', ['$match', '$stateParams', 'urlService', '$state', ($match, $stateParams, urlService, $state)->

    if $match.route and $match.route.length > 0 # you can make more complex route checking here.

        # here transition to the desired type route resolved server side 
        switch typeOfRoute
           #the same for checking.. 
            when "user"
                $state.transitionTo('user.profile', $match, false)
            when "place"
                $state.transitionTo('place.page', $match, false)
    else
        return false    


$stateProvider
    .state('user', {
        abstract: true
        template: '<div ui-view/>'
        })

    .state('user.profile', {
        template: '<h1>This is a profile</h1>'
        controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', ($scope, $state, $stateParams)->

            # Here happens all about the user
        ]})

    .state('place', {
        abstract: true
        template: '<div ui-view/>'
        })

    .state('place.page', {
        template: '<h1>This is a place</h1>'
        controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', ($scope, $state, $stateParams)->

            # Here happens all about the place

        ]})
```